# Is there a Graph API to get all the sign-in activities with AD B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In the Azure AD B2C web portal there is a page to list all the sign-in activities. Is there a Graph API to fetch this data programatically?

I found this documentation which lists how the Audit Logs can be fetched over the Reporting API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs

It uses the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/activities/audit?api-version=beta
```

However it returns all the logged events and not just the sign ins. And I do not find a documentation for exactly this endpoint...

What I did find is the following documentation which shows how signin logs can be retrieved, but it does not seem to work with AD B2C:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hey, have you any more query? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to access user signin information from azure `B2C tennat`.

Right now you would get all activity in your tenant using following request URL:

**URL:** `https://graph.windows.net/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter=category eq 'B2C'`  [See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs#accessing-audit-logs-through-the-azure-ad-reporting-api)

**Permission Required:**  `Read directory data`

**Permission Type:** `Application`

**Note:** Currently only sign in activity not available. See the screen shot below:

[image]

For more information your could refer this official [B2C docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs#accessing-audit-logs-through-the-azure-ad-reporting-api)